# pushing new created object to javascript array overwrites some part of previous data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

When pushing new created object into javascript array, some elements of array becomes same as the last one as if the last pushed object overwrites some parts inside the old ones. As seen below.

```
var urlRoot = "http://.../";
var allBooks = []; 
var i = 1;
var max = 2; //3;

getPage(i);

function getPage(bookNo) {

    if (i > max) {
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: urlRoot + bookNo,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(res) {
            var html = res.responseText;

            allBooks.push(new Book(html));
            //allBooks[i - 1] = new Book(html);

            console.log(allBooks);

            i++;
            getPage(i);
        }
    });
}
```

console.log(allBooks) gives the result below when only two elements pushed and three elements pushed (Value of label 'EnglishbookHeading' changes; but content of array 'Pages' are all same as the last pushed one has.):

```
[Book, Book]
0: Book    
EnglishbookHeading: "Revelation"
Hadiths: Array[43]
__proto__: Book
1: Book    
EnglishbookHeading: "Belief"
Hadiths: Array[43]
__proto__: Book
length: 2
```

---

```
    Array[3]
0: Book
EnglishbookHeading: "Revelation"
Pages: Array[53]
__proto__: Book
1: Book
EnglishbookHeading: "Belief"
Pages: Array[53]
__proto__: Book
2: Book
EnglishbookHeading: "Knowledge"
Pages: Array[53]
__proto__: Book
length: 3
```

*Book.js :*

```
define(["Page"],
    function (Page) {

        var englishbookHeading;
        var thisPages = [];

        function Book(html) {
            setBook(html);

            this.EnglishbookHeading = englishbookHeading;
            this.Pages = thisPages;
        };

        function setBook(html) {
            var con = $(html); //Context

            ...

            var chapters = tumHadisler.find('div.chapter');
            var index = 0;

            chapters.each(function () {

                var Page = new Page();

                ...

                thisPages[index] = Page;

                index++;
            });
        }

        return Book;
    });
```

*Page.js :*

```
define(function () {

    function Page() {

        this.ChapterId = "";

        ...
    }

    return Page;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that `stringify` doesn't mess something up? What's the output of `console.log(allBooks);`?

Comment: Good point, I edited the question after console.log.

Comment: @serefbilge, my suspicion is the code related to book construction. Can you share the relevant code - especially where properties such as `Pages` etc are injected?

Comment: @VinayC, I don't think but I added  Book.js and Page.js to question to be understood more.

Comment: @serefbilge, as suspected, book creation was the issue - your are closing over same pages object in your book constructor. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the issue that you are using the same array object `thisPages` as a value for `Book.Pages` property, so all books will always represent the same value for `Pages` property.

You need to pass `Book` reference to the `setBook` method so that you can add pages to the particular book only. For example,

```
   function Book(html) {
        this.EnglishbookHeading = englishbookHeading;
        this.Pages = [];
        setBook(this, html);
    };

    function setBook(book, html) {
        var con = $(html); //Context

        ...

        var chapters = tumHadisler.find('div.chapter');
        var index = 0;

        chapters.each(function () {

            var Page = new Page();

            ...

            book.Pages[index] = Page;

            index++;
        });
    }
```

Another alternative would be to reset `thisPages` in `setBook` method and that will also do the trick - for example,

```
function setBook(book, html) {
   thisPages = [];   // we are creating new array here that will be used for current book
   var con = $(html); //Context
   ...
```

I am not sure about your coding style and code organization, so choose one that fits you.

Comment: I tried your advice, **the same problem maintains**: var thisPages;
function Book(html) { thisPages = []; setBook(html); ...

Comment: @serefbilge, can you try the first approach - passing book reference in `setBook`? I am not 100% sure if closure would bind with `thisPages` reference or the actual value of `thisPages` - I suspect it to be former, causing the issue.